# How to ssh to my ec2 if i am not using default vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Well, I am almost giving up on aws it is really hard to do simple things here. My problem is I am following this link to setup cpanel for commercial use,
https://blog.cpanel.com/part-2-how-i-built-a-cpanel-hosting-environment-on-amazon-aws/

I set up my VPC, Subnet, Internet Gateways, Elastic IPs and Route Tables and still can not connect to my ec2. it is frustrating that I am wasting time over an ssh problem which can be solved in a matter of seconds in OVH and here AWS ruining my day any ideas?

I set up my VPC, Subnet, Internet Gateways, Elastic IPs and Route Tables

I really expect to connect to my ec2 with ease and be able to add more ec2/s to the service

Comment: Did you open port `22` in the security group? You would have to do that regardless of default vpc.

Comment: Security Groups were configured in Part 1 of that article — did you do that part? By the way, that blog post is from 2013. The Amazon EC2 management console has changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: it was a rocky mistake I did not use the wizard I tried to do it on my own. Solved by using aws wizard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to SSH into an Amazon EC2 instance, you'll need the following:

- An **Amazon VPC** (the default one is fine, or create your own)
- An **Internet Gateway** attached to the VPC (to connect it to the Internet)
- A **public subnet**, which is defined as a subnet that has a route table where the route table sends traffic destined for `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet Gateway
- An **Amazon EC2 instance** in the public subnet, presumably a Linux instance since you want to SSH to it
- When launching the instance, nominate a **Keypair**. If you launch from an Amazon-provided AMI (eg Amazon Linux 2), the keypair will be copied to `/users/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` at startup.
- The instance should either be launched with **Auto-assign Public IP** to receive a random public IP address, or associate the instance with an **Elastic IP address** to associate a static IP address
- A **security group** attached to the EC2 instance permitting inbound SSH access (port 22) either from `0.0.0.0/0` or your own IP address
- Don't play with the **Network Access Control List (NACL)** settings - they default to allowing all traffic in/out

To connect to the instance:

```
ssh -i YOUR-KEYPAIR.pem ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS
```

If the connection is **immediately** rejected, it suggests a problem with the keypair.

If the connection **takes some time** before failing, it suggests a network-related problem because it is unable to contact the instance. Some corporate networks **block outbound SSH access**, so try again from a different network (home vs office, or even tethered via your phone) to try and identify the issue.

Comment: it was a rocky mistake I did not use the wizard I tried to do it on my own. Solved by using aws wizard